# Is JDK necessary for Eclipe when using C++?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, ide

When installing Eclipse Neon for C/C++, I'm required to install either JRE or JDK, does JDK have any benefits over JRE in this case? since I'm not gonna write in Java at all, only C/C++.

Comment: Eclipse itself needs an appropriate Java engine installed. Nothing to do with the CTD c++ features.

Comment: ^^ Which in your case means you only need the JRE to fire up eclipse itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm required to install either JRE or JDK, does JDK have any benefits over JRE in this case? since I'm not gonna write in Java at all, only C/C++

Looks like installing JRE is sufficient. Any of the C/C++ code features won't rely on a JDK. So as long you're not developing Java code the JDK isn't needed.

Comment: Note that on macOS a JDK is required because Eclipse won't run with just the JRE on Macs.

Answer (score 0):

As the name says, the JDK is the *development* kit for Java.

When installing Eclipse only for C/C++ development, installing the JRE should thus be sufficient.

You only need a JVM capable of running eclipse in; and a JRE will do just fine.